# CString Hex value conversion to Byte Array

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion, cstring

I have been trying to carry out a conversion from CString that contains Hex string to a Byte array and have been

unsuccessful so far. I have looked on forums and none of them seem to help so far. Is there a function with just a few

lines of code to do this conversion?

My code:

```
BYTE abyData[8];    // BYTE = unsigned char

CString sByte = "0E00000000000400";
```

Expecting:

```
abyData[0] = 0x0E;
abyData[6] = 0x04; // etc.
```

Comment: your example actually shows each unsigned char containing a string, which isn't right ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply gobble up two characters at a time:

```
unsigned int value(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { return c - '0'; }
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') { return c - 'A' + 10; }
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') { return c - 'a' + 10; }

    return -1; // Error!
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 8; ++i)
{
    abyData[i] = value(sByte[2 * i]) * 16 + value(sByte[2 * i + 1]);
}
```

Of course `8` should be the size of your array, and you should ensure that the string is precisely twice as long. A checking version of this would make sure that each character is a valid hex digit and signal some type of error if that isn't the case.

Comment: @TheNewbie: Good stuff, I'm glad!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(abyData) && (i * 2) < sByte.GetLength(); i++)
{
    char ch1 = sByte[i * 2];
    char ch2 = sByte[i * 2 + 1];

    int value = 0;

    if (std::isdigit(ch1))
        value += ch1 - '0';
    else
        value += (std::tolower(ch1) - 'a') + 10;

    // That was the four high bits, so make them that
    value <<= 4;

    if (std::isdigit(ch2))
        value += ch1 - '0';
    else
        value += (std::tolower(ch1) - 'a') + 10;

    abyData[i] = value;
}
```

**Note:** The code above is *not* tested.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char result[8];
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << "0E00000000000400";
    ss >> *( reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>( result ) );
    std::cout << static_cast<int>( result[1] ) << std::endl;
}
```

however **take care of memory management issues**!!!
Plus the result is in the reverse order as you would expect, so:

```
result[0] = 0x00
result[1] = 0x04
...
result[7] = 0x0E
```

Comment: Why are there "memory management issues"? And why *don't* you mention that this code is undefined behaviour?

Comment: This is not really that helpful when trying to do what I am intending to.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: memory management issues can arise if the number of bytes required for the conversion do not match the size of result[]. Where is the undefined behaviour?